# Mongoose aggregate $facet return even if there aren't any matches

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to use `$facet` to return the count of documents, and skip/limit them as well. The issue is that if there aren't any documents for `$facet`, the aggregation returns undefined.

See [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/--TfzUcSFQn). I was looking into the documentation, and I couldn't find an option for `$facet` to preserve null or empty arrays. Is there a hack for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { key: 3 } },
   {
      $facet: {
         metadata: [
            { $count: "total" }
         ],
         data: [
            { $skip: 1 },
            { $limit: 1 }
         ]
      }
   },
   { $unwind: { path: "$meat", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
])


db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { key: 3 } },
   {
      $facet: {
         metadata: [
            { $count: "total" }
         ],
         data: [
            { $skip: 1 },
            { $limit: 1 }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         metadata: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq: [{ $size: "$metadata" }, 0] },
               then: [{ total: 0 }],
               else: "$metadata"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$metadata" }
])
```